# How to find the next char in a string just to know if the char exists after the previous character in python

Tags: python-3.x

I just want to know if the next char in a string exists or not, I am just posting a small part of the code where I have a problem.

```
num='XMM'
if  num[3]:
    print('empty')
```

I am getting this error :

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

when I simply want something like a True or False evaluation.

I tried using `if not num[3]:`  it does not seem to work as I expect. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `if len(num) > 3:`? What do you mean empty? a space?

Comment: i think this would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could use is a try/except structure :

```
try :
    x = num[3]
    print(x) # or something else you want to do if there is a char
except IndexError:
    print("empty")
```

But note that this is a bad idea and it would be far better to juste use the length of your String:

```
if len(num) <= 3:
    print("empty")
```

Comment: It is better to catch a specific exception (in this case `IndexError`) rather than a blunt `except`

Comment: Why not just ````print(num[3])````?

Comment: As the quesion is not very clear, maybe OP wants to do something with the char if it exists, but there is no difference here you're right

Answer (score 1):

One thing which i feel all the above answers missed, is the fact that python allows us to use -ve indexes :), like below:

```
In [1]: num='XMM'
   ...:

In [2]: num[1]
Out[2]: 'M'

In [4]: num[-3]
Out[4]: 'X'
```

So the right way to check if a index is valid or not is to check as below:

```
In [6]: index_to_check = -1

In [7]: index_to_check in range(-len(num), len(num))
Out[7]: True

In [8]: index_to_check = -4

In [9]: index_to_check in range(-len(num), len(num))
Out[9]: False
```